# WMI error with a simple query in C#

Tags: c#, wmi

I am trying to use this code on Windows 2000:

```
foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
{
    if (p.MainModule.FileName.EndsWith("calc.exe"))
    {
        using (ManagementObjectSearcher mos = 
                   new ManagementObjectSearcher(
                     "SELECT CommandLine,ExecutablePath 
                       FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId=" + p.Id.ToString()))
        {
            using (ManagementObjectCollection moc = mos.Get())
            {
                foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show((string)mo["CommandLine"]);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works on Windows XP and higher, but fails on Windows 2000 with an "Invalid query" error. [According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28VS.85%29.aspx), the Win32_Process object is supported on Windows 2000 and higher, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry everyone. I just realized that the "CommandLine" field is only in Windows XP and higher. Problem solved.