# How to get process Commandline Parameters on Windows 2000 using C#

Tags: c#, wmi

How to get process Commandline Parameters  at Windows 2000 using C#?

I'm use WMI query :select ExecutablePath,CommandLine from Win32_Process where Name='test'
but windows 2000 throw this exception:
system.management.managementexception : invalid query.

so I do not know how to do it work in windows 2000,please help me,
Thank you!

Comment: What are "system process Commandline Parameters"?

Comment: @Oded: sorry for my poor English,i mean,some of the current operating system process

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440932/reading-command-line-arguments-of-another-process-win32-c-code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *CommandLine*-property exists since Windows XP ([msdn source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372(VS.85).aspx)):

> **CommandLine**
>   Data type: string
>   Access type: Read-only
>   Command line used to start a specific process, if applicable. This property is new for Windows XP.

Related SO question: [WMI error with a simple query in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474551/wmi-error-with-a-simple-query-in-c)

Comment: @Nayan: See what I quoted (link in my answer included). MSDN tells me that the `CommandLine`-property is new since XP.

Comment: @guaike: sorry, non that I am aware of